# Using YEAR and SUM CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I am adding all the hours of courses together for the past 3 years and I am having trouble getting the year and sum case when figured out.

THe Code is

```
SELECT TNG_MDA_TYP_CD, SUM(LEN_HRS_ST) AS Expr1, REC_EFF_STT_DT
FROM  dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE_NEW
GROUP BY TNG_MDA_TYP_CD, REC_EFF_STT_DT
```

REC_EFF_STT_DT is the date the course was made available and the LEN_HRS_ST is the total number of hours. I cannot figure out how to incorporate the YEAR function with SUM CASE WHEN. I need a column for each year so a column for 2010, 2011, and 2012 with the total hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing after question was clarified:

```
SELECT 
 TNG_MDA_TYP_CD, 
 Sum2010 = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, REC_EFF_STT_DT) = 2010 THEN LEN_HRS_ST ELSE 0 END),
 Sum2011 = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, REC_EFF_STT_DT) = 2011 THEN LEN_HRS_ST ELSE 0 END),
 Sum2012 = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, REC_EFF_STT_DT) = 2012 THEN LEN_HRS_ST ELSE 0 END)
FROM  dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE_NEW
GROUP BY TNG_MDA_TYP_CD
```

That's assuming that you literally wanted sums for 2010, 2011, and 2012 as you stated. For something more dynamic, take a look at the PIVOT function.

Comment: Sorry I meant to add I needed a column for 2010, 2011, and 2012 with the sums of the hours.

Comment: Edit my initial answer after your clarification.